How to write data to Confluent Kafka with SchemaRegistry format on sparkstructured?
I am to trying write a batch data to kafka topic with schema registry in databricks using pyspark, i serialize the data with pyspark to_avro function and write it to the topic, but the consumers can’t read the schema id. If they do not separate the schema_id first 5 bytes they can read the data as well.
I read the avro schema from .avsc file downloaded in confluent, and it’s version is ok.
df.select(to_avro(carrossel_schema, schema_str)).alias("value")
        .write
        .format('kafka')
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", confluent_server)
        .option("topic", topico)
        .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
        .option(
            "kafka.sasl.jaas.config",
            f"kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='{confluent_user}' password='{confluent_pass}';"
        )
        .option("kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "https")
        .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")
        .save()


    return df

The variable schema_str is the avro schema that has been read. Anyone can help me to serialize this data with schema_id in the few first bytes (Schema Registry Format)?

You need to provide the registry address in the function. Refer https://docs.databricks.com/en/_extras/notebooks/source/schema-registry-integration/avro-data-and-schema-registry.html
